# Can sqlite database corruption and mysteriously undeleted files be the result of flash memory failures?

Tags: android, flash

I have an android phone that is running a database system I made (interaction through SMS and with a cloud end which syncs with it). The main database is stored in an sqlite file. It has been running smoothly on a phone for approximately two years now.

Recently, over the space of about two weeks, I have twice had the database file simply lose all its data (once replaced by a 0 length file and once by a 1k empty file).  Today, a temporary file that the software had deleted in the morning reappeared on its own in the afternoon.

Can this kind of behavior be the result of flash memory decay - i.e. is the phone simply getting old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That certainly *can* be the result of NAND write failures, yeah. Would it be possible to try moving the database to new storage, such as an SD card? While most such cards would wear out faster than the internal storage for the same amount of writing, it may last longer when it's the only thing writing much of anything to the SD.

Of course, if the device memory *is* failing, you're probably in for a new device regardless. The errors usually appear on write, so just running programs and reading existing files may continue to work, but every file you create or modify also writes to the file system metadata (and, due to the way NAND writes work, this will touch file system entries for multiple files). Corruption in the metadata will make the OS unable to find or correctly read other files.

Comment: As you say, moving to an SD card might not help if the main phone crashes. So perhaps better to just get a new device while this one is still functional...